# How to limit max connections for each linux user in vsftpd and ssh

Tags: ssh, ftp, vsftpd, sftp

I'm trying to create a server with few users but limited number of connections each one can have. Suppose the limit is 5. Then a person can connect to ssh (sftp) or vsftpd combined not exceeding 5 concurrent connections.
It can be all 5 ssh or 3 ssh or 2 vsftpd. Once the user has reached this limit, deny the additional connections until current connections are closed.

Is it possible? I

Comment: Hey @user68186, I don't think fail2ban is suited for my needs. I do not want to limit on IP basis but per linux users.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. First of all, by 'users' I am referring to linux users. So, each linux user have those 5 connections limit. It is **not** from same IP but open internet connections.

Comment: Maybe this link can help for the ssh side of the issue ? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196932/how-to-limit-the-number-of-active-logins-per-user